# Uploading video, with PHP serverside formatting & encoding

Tags: php, video, streaming, ffmpeg, jwplayer

We've currently developed an ExpressionEngine site (php), and are using a paid JWPlayer to display video uploaded by the client.

At present we're running into a number of issues, as the client is:

1. Uploading video at the wrong size
2. Uploading video randomly in both flv or mp4 format

And the player is chugging along terribly with multiple pauses throughout the video - sometimes buffering the entire clip before it is played.

I know FFMPEG can be installed serverside, but I'm not sure of the way in which to go about this, and how it might interact between ExpressionEngine and JWPlayer.  I'm also not sure about the formatting - the ability for this automated encoding process to also crop/resize the video to suit the player dimensions on the site.

We would really like to have the videos playable on all browsers & iOS devices.

A HQ option would also be great where applicable, but it's just a nice to have - as we're struggling with the formatting / encoding issues first and foremost.

Any help figuring out the best process, and what tools I might need would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd reccomend using a service like [zencoder](http://zencoder.com/)

I've used them in the past and no matter what video format I've thrown at them it works great. (PS. I'm not affiliated with them at all)

There is a PHP API with a whole lot of resizing, quality and format options. After you've uploaded your video you can send it to zencoder and they'll send you a response some time later with success or fail.

They can put the processed video on Amazon S3 or FTP it to a server.

You'll need a HTML5 player for iOS devices though, unless JWPlayer has come a long way since I used it last.

You could get zencoder to output in mp4. and then you still only need mp4 for JWPlayer/flash and the HTML5 version for iOS, as long as your happy to use flash for all desktop browsers there's no problem.

As far as the buffering issues you are having - I have found that using a CDN version of the swf for JWPlayer (or whatever player you are using) has caused it to load the entire video file before playing.  Easily fixed by hosting it yourself.

Comment: hey James, i using a zencoder and and i need to ask some questions?

Answer (score 1):

I have found many times the video conversion capabilities of different CMS to be limited, and often restricting video formats to what the developers thought was appropriate, such as FLV, which nowadays is turning obsolete for video delivery.

One of the ways you can approach it is by creating a custom script to process the videos uploaded by your client using FFmpeg, which in fact can accept almost any video format, and generate the correct output formats and dimensions, ensuring that the resulting videos will be suitable for web playback using your player.

The problem with the video buffering you are facing is because the video file is not prepared for progressive download or pseudo-streaming, so your browser needs to download the whole video before starting to play. This can be solved with programs like [qt-faststart](http://multimedia.cx/eggs/improving-qt-faststart/) for MP4 and MOV video files, and [flvtool2](http://osflash.org/flvtool2) for FLV files. So your script would need to also optimize the encoded videos using these tools.

Also note that if you use an HTML5 video player (browser native or recent JWPlayer), then you can enjoy from random seeking the video files without buffering them.

If starting from scratch is not an option, you can look into a commercial solution like [tremendum transcoder](http://1stdev.com/tremendum-transcoder/) which also uses FFmpeg and is quite simple to use, yet it does all you need in regards to dealing with different input formats and aspect ratios automatically.

I have done a few setups this way, separating the CMS part from the video processing part, and it saved me some headaches.